# How do I get these pics on top of one another?

Tags: html, css, center

This image shows what currently happens:

[image: Three images with a black background are centered on a page with a grey background. The images are vertically stacked and are spaced so the edges aren't adjacent.],

Here's the code I used:

```
<CENTER><IMG SRC="https://www.fanficparadise.com/gallery/CYOA/extension.png"></CENTER>
<CENTER><IMG SRC="https://www.fanficparadise.com/gallery/CYOA/time.png"></CENTER>
<CENTER><IMG SRC="https://www.fanficparadise.com/gallery/CYOA/extended.png"></CENTER>
```

As you can see, there is a bit of grey between the pics. I was trying to get them to sit on top of one another without any grey between them, but it doesn't work. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Ariel! Unfortunately, without knowing what CSS you have surrounding this (or, if it is being built in a framework: what it is inheriting), you have not presented us with enough information to resolve the problem. Maybe present a working snippet of your code either through https://htmlfiddle.net/ or the StackOverflow Snippet feature to better mimic the environment you intend to use.

Comment: @AaronMorefield always use a stack snippet. Fiddles are only to be used as extension to a stacksnippet but never standalone. If the link would change or the content, the question would hold no further value. Proberly there is no CSS in use and posting it wont be necessary to solve this issue at all.

Comment: Someone has edited my question.

Who did that?

I -do not- like when people hack my account to change how I've done things!*angryface*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.img-container img {
    display:  block;
    margin:  auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/gallery/CYOA/extension.png">
    <img src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/gallery/CYOA/time.png">
    <img src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/gallery/CYOA/extended.png">
</div>
```

A couple of things to note:

1. The `<center>` tag is *very* out of date, so avoid using it.
2. `<img>` tags are inline by default, which will add additional margin/spacing below them. By changing them to `display:block;` we remove that extra white space.
3. Now that the images are set to `display: block`, we can use `margin: auto` to centre-align the images instead of using the deprecated `<center>` tag.

On the chance you cannot modify the CSS, you could also use inline styles:

```html
<img src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/gallery/CYOA/extension.png" style="display: block; margin: auto;">
<img src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/gallery/CYOA/time.png" style="display: block; margin: auto;">
<img src="https://www.fanficparadise.com/gallery/CYOA/extended.png" style="display: block; margin: auto;">
```

Comment: Thanks!^_^

The inline styles were just what I needed now.^_^ They worked perfectly!^_^ Thanks once again.^_^

The only css I'm using is 

body { margin-left: 1%; margin-right: 1%; }

p {text-indent: 1.5em; }

to control page width, and text indent. The rest is old fashioned HTML coding.

My coding knowledge was learned back in the 90s.

Comment: @ArielSchnee No worries :) I started HTML in the 90s too, and a loooot has changed since then! CSS is a powerful thing though, so if you've got time to learn it, I'd definitely recommend it.

Comment: You can see a page with this code at https://www.fanficparadise.com/arielschnee/Code.htm now.